# Brakes sticking in front [2010 Chrysler Town & Country]

Tags: brakes, chrysler, town-and-country

I changed the front brakes & rotors on my 2010 Chrysler Town and Country.  Now the front brakes will not release after driving it for awhile.  They both heat up and sound like they are grinding metal on metal when you try to stop.
What could be the issue here?

Comment: Sounds like a blocked piston, though since it happens on both sides at once may come from excess hydraulic pressure. Have you blead the system of any air inside the pipes? Does the brake pedal feel strange?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though things might not have been put back together correctly. The caliper is two pieces, one with the piston, the other with the bracket which attaches to the suspension. Ensure these are have free movement. They could be rusted inside. Next, check to ensure you put the right pad in the right place. The one with the "squealer" should be on the back side (though I don't know if it goes up or down ... usually it's on the leading edge as the rotor turns, which means it should be towards the back and/or bottom of the caliper, depending on caliper orientation). If they were not put back in correctly, this might be causing the binding. Also, as Alan Ward suggested, ensure the pistons are retracting.